# Relating the Minev et al experiment to Brun QTT survey

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, wavefunction, wavefunction-collapse, experimental-technique

I have been studying from many angles the groundbreaking/now renowned Minev et al experiment: *To catch and reverse a quantum jump mid-flight* [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00545). I have many questions on this complex/intricate setup but alas only 1 is allowed per post. So, I found this excellent QTT (quantum trajectory theory) [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Trajectory_Theory) survey by Brun, which is a great place to start/focus: Brun, *A simple model of quantum trajectories*, [arXiv:0108132](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0108132)

Here is my question:

> Can someone sketch out how the Minev et al experiment relates to the different sections of the QTT survey paper by Brun; and at the answerer's discretion, some indication of the actual "novelty" of this work considering prior science research in the area and related areas?

Some further background: there's some online controversy, with some people are saying that the experiment does not really break new ground because it's essentially combinations of prior work and findings such as Zeno + weak measurements, quantum tomography, etc., and I am wondering if possibly the experimenters did not make the full extent of the novelty of their contributions clear. I may also ask some follow up question(s) based on responses to this one.

Also note that some attention was added recently with this PBS spacetime [episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5HyMNNSGqQ) narrated by Matt O'Dowd, Ph.D. I invite further discussion in [The h Bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) chat for those interested. There is *far* more to say from my own investigation but I am holding off here for now.

Comment: I will only make a short comment. I  must say that I was flabbergasted by the attention this has received. While it is certainly is an important and admirable technological step to the extent that the control of a quantum system goes, insofar as the theory and the interpretation of QM goes there is nothing in there that (I would think, most of) physicists hadn't already known. I remember spending time reading thru the papers -- including some preceding works and experiments that provided the foundation for this -- trying to understand if I missed something.

Comment: The only conclusion I was able to arrive at is that the experimental results illustrate the (fine-grained) conditional tomography of the standard QM dynamic. It certainly and definitely does not reveal anything about quantum measurement or the wave function "collapse."